# String Contains Untranslatable characters - Informatica Teradata ODBc

Tags: unicode, odbc, teradata, informatica

I'm Trying to flow the data from staging table to dimension, in which both the tables are unicode. When i'm loading data from file to my staging table the data is loaded (unicode). But when i'm loading data to Dimension layer table(unicode) from staging, the data is not inserting and the following error is thrown.

Note: I have changed the code page for connection strings in workflow manager, odbc administrator and the table also have unicode charset defined.

```
FnName: Execute -- [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The string contains an untranslatable character.
LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME (LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME:UniChar.255:): "SCIENCES FARMAC->UTICA DO BRASIL LTDA"
  EXTERNAL_VALUE (EXTERNAL_VALUE:UniChar.255:): "G_BR_501"
  PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME (PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME:UniChar.255:): "GLOBAL (ALL COMPANIES)"
  OTHER_PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME1 (OTHER_PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME1:UniChar.255:): "(NULL)"
  OTHER_PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME2 (OTHER_PARENT_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME2:UniChar.255:): "(NULL)"
  COUNTRY_CD (COUNTRY_CD:UniChar.10:): "BR
```

Original data in the staging table is shown below

```
SCIENCES FARMACˆUTICA DO BRASIL LTDA,G_BR_501,(ALL COMPANIES),null,null,BR
```

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: I'd concentrate on the loading in the staging table. It should read "sciences farmacêutica", so if you see that "^" symbol, the data is already "corrupted". Further operation would then be unpredictable. Typically this happens where somewhere there is a wrong "code page": for example you might have configured the original data source (the file system) as Unicode while it is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Hi Insac, Thanks for the reply. However i get the data 'SCIENCES FARMACˆUTICA' in the source file it self. My question is, when i'm loading this record to staging table, but y am i not able to load the same from staging to dim

Comment: What are you using to view the source file?

Comment: This seems to be ODBC issue. Make sure Integration Service runs in Unicode. Check the ODBC properties.